# Renaming bash script's source directory from the script

Tags: linux, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have the following section in my bash script:

```
# Move to script's source directory (in case it's being called from somewhere else)
cd $(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")
# Save script's source directory
pwd=$(pwd)
# If it's not already ~/.cfg
if [ ! "$pwd" -ef ~/.cfg ]; then
        echo "Renaming directory"
        # Move up one level (since you can't rename directory while in it)
        cd ..
        # And rename it
        mv "$pwd" ~/.cfg
fi
```

The script is a setup script for a git repository, to be run right after cloning it. The idea is to move the entire repository to `~/.cfg`. However, I get an error saying

> mv: cannot move '/home/user/config' to '/home/user/.cfg': Permission denied

Permissions are set appropriately and invoking the same `mv` from the command line works without problems.

I'm guessing the problem is that I'm renaming a directory, while the script inside it is still running, and simply moving out of it via `cd` (as in the above snippet) isn't enough. Is there a way to work around that?

---

In the end it turned out I could do something simpler than the accepted answer below, though in the same spirit of running the removal at the very end.

I simply changed the `mv` command to a `cp -r`, then added a `rm -rf "$pwd"` at the very end of the script. Apparently `rm`'s `-f` flag ignores the fact that the script is running. The script now works as intended.

Comment: The easiest workaround I can think of is to put the script in ~/bin/ and add that directory to your path. Have you considered that, and if so, why is that not an easy, workable solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest having two scripts: One that moves everything *except* the first script, and one that just moves the first script and removes the folder.

At the end of the first script, `exec` the second script from the *new* location. That will replace the process and close the handle on the first script. That second script can then move the first script and remove the now-empty original folder.

Something *like*

```
# Move to script's source directory (in case it's being called from somewhere else)
cd $(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")
# Save script's source directory
pwd=$(pwd)
# If it's not already ~/.cfg
if [ ! "$pwd" -ef ~/.cfg ]; then
        echo "Renaming directory"
        # Move up one level (since you can't rename directory while in it)
        cd ..
        # And rename it
        for i in "$pwd"; do
                if [ "$i" != "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" ]; then mv "$i" ~/.cfg; fi
        done
        exec ~/.cfg/script2.sh "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
fi
```

Then script 2:

```
#!/bin/bash
# first arg is path to script you call it from.
base=basename "$1"
dir=dirname "$1"
mv "$1" ~/.cfg/$base
rmdir $dir
```

Comment: Oh I like that, that should work fine.